# Regex to strip spaces and symbols?

Tags: regex

What is the correct regex (I am still learning) to strip everything out of strings (names of people) that is not a letter?

1. Take: "Joe Bloggs". How would you turn this in to (i.e. match) "JoeBloggs" using regex? (No programming language processing).
2. Take "Joe G. Bloggs", "Mary O'Connor", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", "Mark O-Hara" and "J.P. Morgan" all as examples of strings that should contain letters only (i.e. JoeGBloggs", "MaryOConnor", "FScottFitzgerald", "MarkOHara" and "JPMorgan").
3. Can the resulting, letters-only strings also be converted to lower case ("joebloggs", "maryoconnor", "jpmorgan") using regex?

I'm basically trying to see names as usernames.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Regex is a small part of this process. While you could certainly take a regex, and apply it to "Joe Bloggs" and make it match either the space, or both "Joe" and "Bloggs", further functionality would be needed to do something with your matches. Most implementations have a built-in "replace all" for simple regexes (is that even a word?). Furthermore, transforming letter case is not a part of regex. You can match in a case-insensitive way, but again, regex is not a transformation tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\W/g
```

You can match all non-word characters by using an escaped capital `W` or `\W` (lowercase `\w` is word characters).  For javascript flavor of regex this would work as you described:

```
"J.P. Morgan".replace(/\W/g, ''); // results in "JPMorgan"
```